# Расширение файла.

Tags: php

Скажите кто нибудь как убрать с файла расширение в адресной строке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь о расширении `.php` у скриптов, и если конфигурация веб-сервера стандартная, то самый простой вариант: создать папку, а в ней `index.php`.

```
http://domain.com/index.php
http://domain.com/folder/index.php
http://domain.com/folder/index.php?a=b
http://domain.com/folder/index.php?a=b#abcd
```

Тоже самое что и:

```
http://domain.com/
http://domain.com/folder/
http://domain.com/folder/?a=b
http://domain.com/folder/?a=b#abcd
```

Еще есть более сложные варианты с использованием [mod_rewrite](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/php/mod_rewrite.php) для Apache.

Comment: Смотрю вопрос, смотрю ответ. И не вижу связи. О чём вы оба?)

Comment: Тег `php`. Судя по всему человек хочет [ЧПУ][1]

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3_(%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)

Comment: В таком случае совершенно согласен :)

Comment: Ура, экстрасенсы вернулись)

Answer (score 2):

В htaccess вроде так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /$1.php
```

Страница будет достуна по `file.php` и просто `file`